# pandas groupby + count + top 5 highest

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, columnsorting

I know this is a frequently asked question, but I can't manage to make this run.

I have managed to group by a dataframe and find the count based on some other data. Now based on pandas, I want to find to return the top 5 cuisines per country based on the count.

My data is called df3:

| country | cuisines | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Australia | french | 12 |
| Australia | italian | 19 |
| Italy. | Italian | 3 |
| France | Japanese | 5 |
| France | Thailand | 9 |

So far I tried the following, to no avail

```
df3=df3.groupby(['country','cuisines'])['count'].nlargest(5).reset_index()

df3=df3[['country','cuisines']].sort_values(['count'], ascending=False).head(5)
```

Comment: You  want the top 5 per _country_ so your group should _only_ consider the country. Sort then groupby country `df3 = df3.sort_values('count', ascending=False).groupby('country').head(5)` as described by [this answer](/a/50415831/15497888)

Comment: You can also stash the column in the index `df3 = df3.set_index('cuisines').groupby('country')['count'].nlargest(5).reset_index()` as described [here](/a/42266472/15497888)

Comment: thank you for your help, that worked! I guessI got confused in the order of operations -> sorting first, grouping on one column instead of multiple. Thank you for your help !